# Configure a server program to restart after crash

Tags: daemon

I have a web service that runs on Linux.  Is there a conventional way to ensure the server is restarted in the event of a crash?

I suppose I might have a shell script which does something like this:

```
while true; do ./myserver; done
```

But I think the need to attach the script to a session makes this a poor solution.  What is the correct way to do this?

Should there be a daemon process which spawns the server as another daemon?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled by systemd. A very basic service definition file could look like this:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=my server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/myserver
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thanks.  Does the server have to be a daemon, or does it not matter?

Comment: A daemon is an application that runs in the background and provides a service. If your server matches that description it is a daemon.

Comment: OK but I'm asking, can I configure systemd to run my process, without configuring the process as a daemon?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Read systemd.service documentation, and determine what Type you want. Both forking and not ("simple") are supported, pick what the software does.